# Rails has_many through association expected behaviour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm working with four models:`User`, `Group`, `Role` and `UserGroup`.

`Users` can create `Groups` but of course `Users` can also join `Groups` so group ownership/privilidges is determined by a `Role` model.

I'd like to be sure that when a `User` creates a `Group`, the `Group` record is created as well as an associated `UserGroup` with the `user_id` `user_role` and `group_id`.

Below are the models with their associations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups
  has_many :roles, through: :user_groups
end
```

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups
end
```

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups
end
```

```
class UserGroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :place
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Then in the `GroupsController` this is what I initially had:

```
...

def create
   @group = current_user.groups.build(group_params)
end 

private 

def place_params 
  params.require(:group).permit(:name)
end
```

This successfully creates a group but not the `user_group` association, what am I missing?

Something like this works as expected:

```
def create
  @group = Group.build(group_params)
  if @group.save 
    @user_group = current_user.user_groups.build(role_id: 1, group: @group)

...
```

That feels a bit verbose and cumbersome, is there a way to do this with just one line so that I could build and validate the `group` with the associated `user_group` before saving one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, your logic is two steps.

1. create group,
2. add the current user (with role) to the group.

Step 1 requires user input (name). However, step 2 does not require user input.

If I have to code I will do like this

```
@group = Group.new(group_params) 
@group.user_groups.build(user: current_user, role_id: 1)
@group.save
```

If you are accepting users list in the frontend, you have to make use of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

```
# group.rb
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_groups, 
                                reject_if: ->(attrs) { attrs['user_id'] == '0' || attrs['role_id'].blank? # and check other attributes for validity }
```

```
# controller.rb
@group = Group.new(group_params).tap |gp|
  gp.user_groups.build(user: current_user, role_id: 1)
end
@group.save
```

Comment: I like this it seems to be quite elegant but how do I specify the user's role?  Simply ading a user to the group does not work: 
` @group.users << User.first`  returns `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Role must exist)`

Comment: can you update your question with models/user_groups.rb ?

Comment: Sorry I have added that now.